# How to create 6 new columns based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
        TMAX  TMIN    PP
CODE                  
000130   990  1026  1033
000132   799  1160   711
000134  1727  1680  1730
000135   576   626   791
000136  1348  1242  1203
     ...   ...   ...
000543   927   902  1341
000546   168   167   263
000547   383   359   315
000548   372   393   601
000549   811   896   919

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to create 6 new colums. The first three columns will be TMAXYEAR, TMINYEAR and PPYEAR like this:

```
df['TMAXYEAR']=df['TMAX']/365
df['TMINYEAR']=df['TMIN']/365
df['PPYEAR']=df['PP']/365
```

The other columns will be TMAXPERC TMINPERC and PPERC:

```
df['TMAXPERC']=df['TMAX']*100/10958
df['TMINPERC']=df['TMIN']*100/10958
df['PPERC']=df['PP']*100/10958
```

I want to know if there is another more efficient way to do this. I'm also thinking in:

```
dfyear=df[['TMAX','TMIN','PP']]/365
dfperc=df[['TMAX','TMIN','PP']]*100/10958
```

And then join those two df's (dfyear and dfperc) but i still believe there is other more eficcient way.

Would you mind to help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think make the change columns in a `list` will more easy to maintain in the future

```
l = ['TMAX','TMIN','PP']
df = df.join((df[l]/365).add_suffix('YEAR').join((df[l]*100/10958).add_suffix('PERC')))
df
Out[167]: 
      TMAX  TMIN    PP  TMAXYEAR  ...    PPYEAR   TMAXPERC   TMINPERC     PPPERC
CODE                              ...                                           
130    990  1026  1033  2.712329  ...  2.830137   9.034495   9.363022   9.426903
132    799  1160   711  2.189041  ...  1.947945   7.291477  10.585873   6.488410
134   1727  1680  1730  4.731507  ...  4.739726  15.760175  15.331265  15.787552
135    576   626   791  1.578082  ...  2.167123   5.256434   5.712721   7.218471
136   1348  1242  1203  3.693151  ...  3.295890  12.301515  11.334185  10.978281
[5 rows x 9 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create several columns at once, try:

```
l_cols=df.columns 
#or if you limit the columns l_cols=['TMAX', 'TMIN', 'PP']
df[l_cols + 'YEAR'] = df[l_cols]/365
df[l_cols + 'PERC'] = df[l_cols]*100/10958
print(df)
```